# The right way to include multiple fonts in css

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I don't a simple moment. Which way is the right way to include multiple fonts in css? Here are simple examples.

This?

```
@font-face {
font-family: DeliciousRomanRegular;
src: url(/Delicious-Roman-R.otf);
}

@font-face {
font-family: DeliciousRomanBold;
src: url(/Delicious-Roman-B.otf);
}
```

or this?

```
@font-face {
font-family: Roman;
src: url(/Delicious-Roman-R.otf);
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: Roman;
src: url(/Delicious-Roman-B.otf);
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

And why? 
I use the second one, because I can add font-family to BODY and just add font-style or font-weight to other classes. And it works.

But I saw people using the first method many times. But it seems to me too rude.
Every time you need to add bold to a class you have to use "font-family: DeliciousRomanRegular, Arial, sans-serif;". WTF?

Comment: I always use the second. Pretty much for the same reasons you described :)

Comment: People use the first method because they're ignorant and don't know the right way to do things.

Comment: People who do use the first one think that in the second one the style and weight are being set globally. May not be everyone's need you see.

Comment: Actually both methods have positives and negatives...  Here is a good article covering each method, and the corresponding device support. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/14/setting-weights-and-styles-at-font-face-declaration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option: you use the same font name, but for each variant you intend to use, you need to specify (a) the variation and (b) the alternate resource to use as font.

This ensures that in your actual content CSS you can do things like:

```
p {
  font-family: Roman;
  font-style: regular;
  font-weight: 400;
}

p em {
  font-style: italic;
}

p strong {
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

And things will work correctly. Contrast this to the ridiculous notion of "changing the font family just because you wanted the same font, but italic". Let's not do that.